# Perl checkbox check based on database value

Tags: html, perl, postgresql, checkbox

I have a set of checkboxes like these but was wondering how to approach checking them be default based on the values in the database.

```
<input type="checkbox" name = "others_post" id = "others_post" value="1"> Other's Posts <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name = "clients_post" id = "clients_post" value="1"> Cilent's Post <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name = "assigned_tasks" id = "assigned_tasks" value="1"> Task Assigned
```

This Perl script holds all the database values:

```
my $prefs = USystems::UserPrefs->new($user->userid);
```

I found something similar on a PHP thread which is exactly what I want but with Perl
[PHP checkbox set to check based on database value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239663/php-checkbox-set-to-check-based-on-database-value)

I'm not very fimiliar with Perl so I dont know if there was syntax like the PHP example that you can insert into the checkboxes?

Comment: Where did you stuck, at retrieving data from database or adding `checked` into `<input>`?

Comment: I don't know how to check for a database entry and check the checkbox depending on the value in the database. I'm not sure if such a command exists like in PHP or what it looks like

Comment: First you'll need some database model and be familiar with it.

Comment: I added the Perl script that has all the information for the checkboxes from the database

Comment: Are you familiar with your framework and database model?

Comment: Pretty basic understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name = "others_post" id = "others_post" value="1" <% if ($prefs->{OTHERS_POST} == 1){print 'checked'} %>> Other's Posts <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name = "clients_post" id = "clients_post" value="1" <% if ($prefs->{CLIENTS_POST} == 1){print 'checked'} %>> Cilent's Post <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name = "assigned_tasks" id = "assigned_tasks" value="1" <% if ($prefs->{ASSIGNED_TASKS} == 1){print 'checked'} %>> Task Assigned
```

Assuming that your `$prefs` has all the information you needed stored in it. Just put in an Perl if statement that checks to see if the database value is 1. If it is than print `checked` which will give the checkbox the `checked` attribute and check it.