# Check checkboxes from database values php

Tags: php

I have the following code. I want to get the checkboxes checked based on database values. When I write the code in the while I get the group of buttons many times as the buttons checked I have, but anyway I get the right buttons checked. When out of while the code is, I get  **Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given** . What can I do ?

```
 <?php
   $query=" select description from doors
            where id_doors IN
            (select doors_id_doors from access_rights 
            where users_rfidcode='".$result['rfidcode']."'); ";

   $resultt=$conn->query($query);
       while($row=$resultt->fetch_assoc()){}
            //in_array ()check if value is in array 
               if(in_array("SW1",$row))echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="SW1" checked >SW1'; else echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="SW1"  >SW1';
               if(in_array("SW2",$row))echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="SW2" checked >SW2';  else echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="SW2"  >SW2';
               if(in_array("SW3",$row))echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="SW3" checked >SW3';  else echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="SW3"  >SW3';
               if(in_array("PR1",$row))echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="PR1" checked >PR1';  else echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="PR1"  >PR1';
               if(in_array("PR2",$row))echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="PR2" checked >PR2';  else echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="PR2"  >PR2';
   ?>
```

Comment: Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Your connection information?

Comment: $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

Comment: It's included in other file the connection, here comes with require_once "db.php";

Comment: Why not `$resultt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: I don't work with PDO but with mysqli,can you tell me where the problem in my code is that it doesn't work ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP checkbox set to check based on database value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239663/php-checkbox-set-to-check-based-on-database-value)

Comment: @Terminus I did it not in that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you closed the bracket then you write the code of html, so try this:

```
<?php
   $query=" select description from doors
            where id_doors IN
            (select doors_id_doors from access_rights 
            where users_rfidcode='".$result['rfidcode']."'); ";

   $resultt=$conn->query($query);
       while($row=$resultt->fetch_assoc()){
            //in_array ()check if value is in array 
               if($row['description'] =="SW1") echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="SW1" checked >SW1'; else echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="SW1"  >SW1';
               if($row['description'] =="SW2") echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="SW2" checked >SW2';  else echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="SW2"  >SW2';
               if($row['description'] =="SW3") echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="SW3" checked >SW3';  else echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="SW3"  >SW3';
               if($row['description'] =="PR1") echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="PR1" checked >PR1';  else echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="PR1"  >PR1';
               if($row['description'] =="PR2")  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="PR2" checked >PR2';  else echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="PR2"  >PR2';
}
   ?>
```

also you can improve your code to more readable:

```
    <?php
   $query=" select description from doors
            where id_doors IN
            (select doors_id_doors from access_rights 
            where users_rfidcode='".$result['rfidcode']."'); ";

   $resultt=$conn->query($query);
       while($row=$resultt->fetch_assoc()){
            //in_array ()check if value is in array 

                $SW1_checked='';
                $SW2_checked='';
                $SW3_checked='';
                $PR1_checked='';
                $PR2_checked='';
               if($row['description'] =="SW1") {$SW1_checked='checked';} 
               elseif($row['description'] =="SW2") {$SW2_checked='checked';}
               elseif($row['description'] =="SW3") {$SW3_checked='checked';}
               elseif($row['description'] =="PR1") {$PR1_checked='checked';}
               elseif($row['description'] =="PR2") {$PR2_checked='checked';}


}
             echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="SW1" '.$SW1_checked.' >SW1'; 
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="SW2"  '.$SW2_checked.' >SW2';  
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="SW3"  '.$SW3_checked.' >SW3';  
             echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="PR1"  '.$PR1_checked.' >PR1';  
             echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="PR2"  '.$PR2_checked.' >PR2';  
   ?>
```

Comment: can you print_r($row['description']); and see what is the result?

Comment: When I write the if-code in the while I get  the buttons checked but soo many times like this SW1  ✓ SW2   SW3   PR1   PR2   SW1   SW2   ✓ SW3   PR1   PR2 SW1   SW2    SW3   PR1  ✓ PR2

Comment: So if I have 3 values to be checked I get three times the group of checkboxes with the checked values

Comment: if this the problem you can remove else like I edit the above code

Comment: It happens the same thing as before. I get the buttons checked but soo many times like this SW1 ✓ SW2 SW3 PR1 PR2 SW1 SW2 ✓ SW3 PR1 PR2 SW1 SW2 SW3 PR1 ✓ PR2  So if I have 3 values to be checked I get three times the group of checkboxes with the checked values

Comment: @iris Remove the `_checked` variables' initialization and the echoes of the checkboxes from the loop. And to make it dynamic, use an associative array to store the isChecked.