# In PHP how to Keep the values in the form for check box?

Tags: php, html, checkbox

This is my HTML code

```
<label>Subject : </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="subject" id="subject[]" value="Maths"/>Maths</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="subject" id="subject[]" value=English"/>English</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="subject" id="subject[]" value="Tamil"/>Tamil</label>
```

and this is php code

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="subject" id="subject[]" <?php if (isset($_POST["subject"]) && $_POST["subject"]=="Maths") echo "checked";?> value = "Maths"/>Maths
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="subject" id="subject[]" <?php if (isset($_POST["subject"]) && $_POST["subject"]=="English") echo "checked";?> value = "English"/>English
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="subject" id="subject[]" <?php if (isset($_POST["subject"]) && $_POST["subject"]=="Tamil") echo "checked";?> value = "Tamil"/>Tamil
</label>
```

but is not working.

Comment: your subject is an array^^ not a string

Comment: Please don't overwrite edits which improve the readability of the question (add to the edited version of the question instead)

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP checkbox set to check based on database value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239663/php-checkbox-set-to-check-based-on-database-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the correct code.

```
<label>Subject : </label>
            <label><input type = "checkbox" name = "subject[]" id = "subject" <?php echo (in_array("Maths",$_POST["subject"]))?"checked" : " "?> value = "Maths"/>Maths</label>
            <label><input type = "checkbox" name = "subject[]" id = "subject" <?php echo (in_array("Maths",$_POST["subject"]))?"checked" : " "?> value = "English"/>English</label>
            <label><input type = "checkbox" name = "subject[]" id = "subject" <?php echo (in_array("Maths",$_POST["subject"]))?"checked" : " "?> value = "Tamil"/>Tamil</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call all the checkboxes the same name then they need to be an array

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" id="subject[]" <?php if (isset($_POST["subject"][0]) && $_POST["subject"][0]=="Maths") echo "checked";?> value = "Maths"/>Maths
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" id="subject[]" <?php if (isset($_POST["subject"][1]) && $_POST["subject"][1]=="English") echo "checked";?> value = "English"/>English
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" id="subject[]" <?php if (isset($_POST["subject"][2]) && $_POST["subject"][2]=="Tamil") echo "checked";?> value = "Tamil"/>Tamil
</label>
```

Comment: Sorry, I fixed a typo, see the second and third `<input>` now. All need to be `name="subject[]"`