# HTML Input Checkbox Value Checked

Tags: php, html

I am processing an html form using php. My question is specifically about input type checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkme" value="checked" <***php echo $data['checkme']; ***> >
```

This works for me because, on load, $data['checkme'] = ""; and on error, $data['checkme'] = "checked". I have searched quite a bit regarding this, and there are plenty of suggestions for setting the value of the checkbox input. But not in this way (that I found). This works, but I want to make sure I am not creating a problem that I don't foresee.

My question: Is this good practice?

Comment: Is `checked` HTML5? I thought previous format was `checked="checked"`. Anyway, back to the real question, I usually have it as `if(!empty().. { echo 'checked="checked"';}`

Comment: The way you found seems like first answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239663/php-checkbox-set-to-check-based-on-database-value. With the exception that if `$data` or   `checkme` don't exist you'll throw a notice.

Comment: The form initializes with $data['name'], $data['address'],...etc. The array values are empty upon initialization, and populated with user input if the user needs to make correction. If $data doesn't exist, every field of the form will throw a notice. I appreciate the link to question # 16239663. I had not found that in my previous search. Thanks