# Onclick not working with Toggle button, but works just fine with a regular HTML button

Tags: javascript, ajax

Onclick not working with Toggle button, but works just fine with a regular HTML button

Here is my code:

```
<!-- This works fine -->
<td>
    <button onclick="updateStatus(<?php echo $comp['id'];?>)" id="statusBtn<?php echo $comp['id'];?>" class="status-btn <?php echo $comp['status']==0?'done':'pending'; ?>">
        <?php echo $comp['status']==0?'Done':'Pending'; ?>
    </button>
</td>

<!-- This doesn't I need the same as above with the below Toggle Button see screenshot -->  
<td>      
    <input type="checkbox" 
        data-toggle="toggle" 
        data-size="small" 
        data-onlabel="Done" 
        data-offlabel="Pending" 
        data-onstyle="success" 
        data-offstyle="warning" 
        onclick="updateStatus(<?php echo $comp['id']; ?>)" <?php echo $comp['status']==0?'done':'pending';?>
        <?php echo $comp['status']==0?'Done':'Pending'; ?> />                                                               
</td>
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you.

---

**Added from comments:**

```
const updateStatus=function(id) { 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "do_switch.php", 
        data:{ updateId:id }, 
        dataType: "html", 
        success: function(data){ 
            if(data==1) { 
                $("#statusBtn"+id).text("Pending") } 
            else if(data==0) { 
                $("#statusBtn"+id).text("Done")
            } // change status btn colors 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

and also:

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" 
        data-toggle="toggle" 
        data-size="small" 
        data-onlabel="Done" 
        data-offlabel="Pending" 
        data-onstyle="success" 
        data-offstyle="warning" 
        value="Done" 
        onclick="updateStatus(<?php echo $comp['id']; ?>)" <?php echo $comp['status']==0?'done':'pending';?> <?php echo $comp['status']==0?'Done':'Pending'; ?> > 
</td>
```

[image]

Comment: It's probably the toggle button library you're using, preventing the onclick event from bubbling. Your code works just fine in plain HTML. All clicks trigger the `updateStatus` function.

Comment: I am not sure which one to use, I am using Bootstrap 5..

Comment: Try without bootstrap by commenting out the relevant pieces of markup

Comment: When I comment Bootsrap 5 cdn, it becomes a Simple Checkbox and it works fine, but I need it as a toggle Button... that's where I am stuck.. Thank you.!

Comment: You do not appear to actually set a value of the `checkbox` input element

Comment: It wasn't set un the Button part and it is working fine as I mentioned !

Comment: @Augustine What does the documentation of the toggle switch say about click events?

Comment: a `button` does not have a value attribute as such - the value is really what is inside the element. A regular `input` element, such as a `checkbox` does have a value attribute. It is not clear in the above what you actually updating within the input element if it is not the value... What would be more useful would be to look at (copy & paste) the rendered HTML (ie: view source ) to see what these input elements look like

Comment: can you share you js code for `updateStatus()`?

Comment: I tried value="done", not working either ! :
<td>      
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle"           
         data-size="small" data-onlabel="Done" data-offlabel="Pending" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="warning" value="Done"
         onclick="updateStatus(<?php echo $comp['id']; ?>)" <?php echo $comp['status']==0?'done':'pending';?>
         <?php echo $comp['status']==0?'Done':'Pending'; ?> >                
       </td>

Comment: Ajax code:
<script>
const updateStatus= function(id)
{
    $.ajax({    
        type: "POST",
        url: "do_switch.php", 
        data:{updateId:id},            
        dataType: "html",                  
        success: function(data){  
      
           if(data==1)
     {
            $("#statusBtn"+id).text("Pending")
           }
    else if(data==0)
       {
     $("#statusBtn"+id).text("Done")
       }
           // change status btn colors
           
           
        }
    });

}
</script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't tell us, what toggle switch library you're using, there's some guessing involved.

These "switches" usually mask the underlying checkbox and this particular one does not seem to trigger the `click event` for the checkbox. The switch should change the `checked state` of the checkbox though (so it can be submitted via a form submit). So I'd try to change the `onclick` to `onchange`.

**Edit**: The plugin in question is [bootstrap5-toggle](https://palcarazm.github.io/bootstrap5-toggle/).

So the code for your checkboxes should look something like:

```php
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-onlabel="Done" data-offlabel="Pending" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="warning" onchange="updateStatus(<?php echo $comp['id']; ?>)" <?php echo $comp['status']==0?'':'checked';?>>
```

Comment: Bingo@volkerschulz
Something is changing when i used onchange... some light at the end of this tunnel for sure... let me try more .. Thank you !

Comment: Sure. It wouldn't harm if you provided a link to the library you're using by editing your question tho. ;)

Comment: Sure here they are :
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap5-toggle@5.0.4/css/bootstrap5-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap5-toggle@5.0.4/js/bootstrap5-toggle.ecmas.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/jq-3.7.0/dt-1.13.6/b-2.4.2/b-html5-2.4.2/date-1.5.1/r-2.5.0/sc-2.2.0/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: I ran into an issue now, although the Toggle is writing to mysql table, when I refresh it doesn't stick, all tags are back to "Pending" eventhough they are "Done" in the table ...:-(

Comment: The link would be this one then: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap5-toggle and there's an `Events` section with examples.

Comment: `when I refresh it doesn't stick` - That is probably because you don't set `checked` for the checkboxes depending on the status.

Comment: @Augustine See top answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239663/php-checkbox-set-to-check-based-on-database-value